# Changes to laravel 4.2 website is not being reflected

Tags: php, laravel, caching, model-view-controller, laravel-4.2

I am new to laravel framework. I am trying to edit laravel webapplication.

Website is running in EC-2 instance of AWS. I am doing SCP with filezilla.

I found that /var/www/html/app has one route.php file.

any changes in route.php file or any changes in views, controller folder is not getiing reflected to my website.
even i delete some files , then also it does not reflects.

I tried

```
/var/www/html$ php artisan cache:clear
```

does not work.
Why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

These steps should be enough

1. Check if files are properly uploaded.
2. clear cache of laravel as well as web server if you are using any
3. Restart web server